# Data returned to SSRS not the same as SSMS Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am totally stumped.

I have the below SQL query that runs fine in SSMS, I then add the query to SSRS and everything is all weird.

Some data lines are omitted for no obvious reason and the values in the WABill and WACost are also changed when reflecting on the report.

I have cleared the rdl.data in the projects folder, no luck.

I have a sneaky suspicion it might have something to do with the GROUP BY

The Report is Setup has the date parameters defined and the dates are selected of the date picker.

I add the SQL Script as Text on the DataSet

I will appreciate your help.

```
Declare @ToDate DateTime
Declare @FromDate DateTime
Declare @WACost as Numeric (18,2)
Declare @WABill as Numeric (18,2)


Set @FromDate = '20160501'
Set @ToDate = '20160510'

Set @WACost = (
              Select
                    sum(dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + Sum((dbo.FleetData.OwnCost + dbo.FleetData.OpCost)
                    * dbo.DataInput.Hrs)
              From       dbo.DataInput INNER JOIN
                         dbo.HRData ON dbo.DataInput.HRId = dbo.HRData.HRId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetData ON dbo.FleetData.FleetId = dbo.DataInput.FleetId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.WorkCodes ON dbo.DataInput.WorkCodeId = dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID
             WHERE ProdDate >= @FromDate AND ProdDate <= @ToDate and dbo.workcodes.WorkCode = 101
              ) 

Set @WABill = (
              Select
                sum(dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + Sum((dbo.FleetData.OwnBill + dbo.FleetData.OpBill)
                * dbo.DataInput.Hrs)
              From dbo.Datainput Inner Join
                   dbo.FleetData ON dbo.FleetData.FleetId = dbo.DataInput.FleetId INNER JOIN
                   dbo.HRData ON dbo.DataInput.HRId = dbo.HRData.HRId INNER JOIN
                   dbo.WorkCodes ON dbo.DataInput.WorkCodeId = dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID

              WHERE ProdDate >= @FromDate AND ProdDate <= @ToDate and dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode = 101
              )

SELECT     

             @WACost as WACostTotal, @WABill as WABillTotal,

              dbo.DataInput.DataInputID as DataInpID, dbo.DataInput.ProdDate as ProdDate, dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode as WCode, dbo.DataInput.Hrs as ProdHrs, dbo.DataInput.Loads as ProdLoads, 
              dbo.DataInput.Fuel as ProdFuel, dbo.FleetData.FleetNo as ProdFltNo, dbo.JobCodes.JobCode, 
              dbo.FleetType.EquipmentType as EqType, dbo.FleetModel.ModelName as Model, dbo.Sites.SiteName as ProdSiteName, 
              dbo.JobCodes.JobDetails as JCDet, dbo.JobCodes.BillMeth as BillM,
              dbo.FleetData.OwnCost as FltOwnCost, dbo.fleetdata.OpCost as FltOpCost, dbo.fleetdata.OwnBill as FltOwnBill,
              dbo.FleetData.OpBill as FltOpBill,

              (dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize * dbo.DataInput.Loads) as ProdBCM,
              dbo.HRData.EmpNo as HREmp, dbo.HRData.RatePH as EmpCost, dbo.HRData.RateBill as EmpBill, 
              dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs as ProdShHrs, dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize as MSize, 
              (dbo.DataInput.Fuel * dbo.JobCodes.FuelRate) as ProdFuelCost,
              dbo.budget.BudDate as BdgDate, dbo.Budget.RevBCM as BdgRevBCM, dbo.Budget.PricePerBCM as BdgBCMPrice,
              dbo.budget.BCMValue as BdgBCMVal, dbo.budget.SalWage as BdgSalWage, dbo.budget.Fuel as FuelBdg, 
              dbo.budget.PG0 as PGZero, dbo.budget.PG as PGCP,
              dbo.budget.siteId as BudgSite,

              --BILLING CALCS

              --PG Billing
              IIF(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.Budget.SalWage * (1 + dbo.Budget.SalWagePerc)) + dbo.budget.PG0 + 
              (dbo.budget.PG * (1 + PGPerc)),0) as PGBill,

              --FleetBill
              IIF(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as FleetBill,

              --LabourCost
              iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill),0) as LabourBill,  

              --Total Variable Bill
              iif(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + 
               (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as TotalVarBill,

               --WABill
               iif(dbo.Workcodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + 
               (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs) / 
               @WABill * ((dbo.Budget.SalWage * (1 + dbo.Budget.SalWagePerc)) + dbo.budget.PG0 + 
              (dbo.budget.PG * (1 + PGPerc))) +
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RateBill) + 
               (FleetData.OwnBill + FleetData.OpBill) * DataInput.Hrs) , 0) as WABill,

              --COST CALCS

              --PG Cost

              IIF(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.Budget.SalWage + dbo.budget.PG0 + dbo.budget.PG),0) as PGCost,

              --FLEETCOST
              IIF(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as FleetCost,

              --LabourCost
              iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
              (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH),0) as LabourCost,

               --Total Variables Cost
               iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               (dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs,0) as TotalVarCost,

               --WAOnly
               iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs) / 
               @WACost * (dbo.Budget.SalWage + dbo.budget.PG0 + dbo.budget.PG),0)
               as WACalc,

               --WA
               iif(dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode  = 101,
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs) / 
               @WACost * (dbo.Budget.SalWage + dbo.budget.PG0 + dbo.budget.PG) +
               ((dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs * dbo.HRDATA.RatePH) + 
               (FleetData.OwnCost + FleetData.OpCost) * DataInput.Hrs) , 0) as WACost


FROM            dbo.DataInput INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetData ON dbo.FleetData.FleetId = dbo.DataInput.FleetId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetMake ON dbo.FleetData.FleetMakeId = dbo.FleetMake.FleetMakeId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetModel ON dbo.FleetData.FleetModelId = dbo.FleetModel.ModelId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FleetType ON dbo.FleetData.FleetTypeId = dbo.FleetType.FleetTypeId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.HRData ON dbo.DataInput.HRId = dbo.HRData.HRId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Sites ON dbo.DataInput.SiteId = dbo.Sites.SiteId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Budget ON dbo.Sites.SiteId = dbo.Budget.SiteId AND dbo.DataInput.Period = dbo.Budget.Period INNER JOIN
                         dbo.WorkCodes ON dbo.DataInput.WorkCodeId = dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.JobCodes ON dbo.DataInput.JobCodeId = dbo.JobCodes.JobCodeId

WHERE ProdDate >= @FromDate AND ProdDate <= @ToDate

Group By dbo.DataInput.DataInputID, dbo.DataInput.DataInputID, dbo.DataInput.ProdDate, dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCode, dbo.DataInput.Hrs,
              dbo.DataInput.Loads, dbo.DataInput.Fuel, dbo.FleetData.FleetNo, dbo.JobCodes.JobCode, 
              dbo.FleetType.EquipmentType, dbo.FleetModel.ModelName, dbo.Sites.SiteName, 
              dbo.JobCodes.JobDetails, dbo.JobCodes.BillMeth, dbo.FleetData.OwnCost, dbo.fleetdata.OpCost, 
              dbo.fleetdata.OwnBill, dbo.FleetData.OpBill,dbo.HRData.EmpNo, dbo.HRData.RatePH, dbo.HRData.RateBill, 
              dbo.DataInput.ShiftHrs, dbo.FleetModel.ModelSize, dbo.budget.BudDate, dbo.Budget.RevBCM, dbo.Budget.PricePerBCM,
              dbo.budget.BCMValue, dbo.budget.SalWage, dbo.budget.Fuel, dbo.budget.PG0, dbo.budget.PG,
              dbo.budget.siteId, dbo.jobcodes.FuelRate, dbo.datainput.workcodeid, dbo.budget.SalWagePerc, dbo.Budget.PGPerc, 
              dbo.WorkCodes.WorkCodeID  

Order By dbo.DataInput.ProdDate
```

Report:

[image]

When Looking at the value for DataInputID it should be 1715.41

Comment: delete the rdl file from report-server and deploy it again

Answer (score 1):

Where to start? Check/do the following:

1. Pointing at the same database?
2. Using the same dataset with the same parameters
3. Cleared the cache down?
4. Check the report isn't filtering.
5. Check the report isn't aggregating.